# Cisco switch basic setup for a simple private lan

Tags: networking, router, private-network

I have a 'private' LAN. There is a 10-port Cisco SG300-10 switch, with 5 laptops connected to it. No Internet is desired & no routers are present. Each laptop should be able to ping the other 4. Preferably the 5 laptops have static addresses (192.168.1.2,3,4,5 is good enough)

Management console (192.168.1.254) works fine, and so does ssh.

Since I am new to the world of switches, here are my questions/assumptions :

1) How do I associate a Mac address with an IP address in the 192.168.1.x range, for the above setup.

2) Do I need to configure a VLAN at all (to achieve the above) ? There is a default VLAN1 created. I'm not planning to (at least initially) segment ports etc. Also, the system configuration indicates its in L2 mode.

Please guide me to the minimum configs I need to do on the switch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't associate a mac-address with an ip-address in the switch. There is no need for the switch to have this information at all. It is a layer-2 device so it doesn't care about IP (except for its own ip-address for it's management interface).

You set the ip-addresses manually on the individual PC's (as you have already done) or you use a DHCP server. (This switch doesn't have a DHCP server on-board.)

Putting everything in VLAN1 (the default) is fine for your use-case. You can always setup VLAN's later, but then to communicate between those VLAN's you will need an extra router. (This switch can't act as router.)

The SG300 is just a basic switch in it's default config and that is exactly what you want/need. Just initialize it to factory-default and you are done.

Comment: @blispr I have installed literally hundreds of these switches, they are our GP switch for commercial and VoIP installations. Tonny is absolutely correct, as the switch comes out of the box or factory reset and the switch will be ready for your purpose as described.

Comment: Yep, second that vote. I have these at home, and have installed more then I care to remember. This info is correct.

Comment: @acejavelin What I really like about them is that out-of-the-box they act just as a dumb switch. But VLAN's, RSTP, BPDU filtering is all there if you need it and fairly easy to configure. Granted: they are not the best in the world (they can get congested if you throw too much broadcast/multicast at them), but for the price they are really nice.